# two different domain names accessing the same server / application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, url

we have a Ruby on Rails application deployed to AWS using EKS. We are planning to `update` the application URL from

```
https://old_subdomain.old_domain.com 
to 
https://new_subdomain.new_domain.com
```

for a while (3 weeks or so), we plan to have both the URLS active and after that set a redirect in the `ingress.yml` from old to new URL.

Could there be any issues resulting out of this by having two different urls serving the same application for a while?

Thanks.

Comment: Terminate TLS in the ingress. Make sure the application writes HTML links correctly and sends HTTP redirects to the correct domain.

Comment: thanks for your reply. sorry i did not fully follow, can you please elaborate more on "Terminate TLS in the ingress"

Comment: You can define two hosts in the ingress for the two domain names and terminate TLS there with separate certs for the two domains.

Comment: yes, i have defined two hosts in the ingress controller with also separate SSL certificates for each domain.